# Looking for a class or something similar to create a log of while classes and functions a script calls

Tags: php, class, logging, listener

I'm looking for a PHP class or something that can be called at the start of a script that will log every class and function and variables passed into each of these as the script executes. The goal is to be able to dump a process flow of what my script did in the event of something not performing correctly.

The key: I don't want to have to add log->thisAction("blah"); everywhere, I just want to create a listener at the beginning that tracks everything automatically.

Anyone know of a) how to do this, b) if something exists already?

Answer (score 0):

[NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) does application-level monitoring in multiple platforms.  It's commercial, but not overly expensive.  Definitely worth it for commercial projects.